# Binding Map to Scala properties

Tags: json, scala

I have a json data as

> {"query":{"count":1,"created":"2014-04-28T07:33:09Z","lang":"en-US","results":{"rate":{"id":"USDCNY","Rate":"6.2489","Date":"4/28/2014","Time":"3:30am","Ask":"6.2494","Bid":"6.2484"}}}}

from above.,

I am interested only in

> {"id":"USDCNY","Rate":"6.2489","Date":"4/28/2014","Time":"3:30am","Ask":"6.2494","Bid":"6.2484"}

data

I extracted it as a Map,

```
  val translateAPI = url(yahooFinanceApiUrl)
  val response = Http(translateAPI OK as.String)

  response onComplete {
    case Success(json) => parser(json)
    case Failure(error) => println(" Error " +error)
  }


  def parser(data:String) = {

    val languages = JSON.parseFull(data) match {
     case Some(x:Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, Any]]]) => {
     (x.get("query")).last.get("results").last.get("rate").last
   }
  case None => Nil
}

println(languages)
```

}

I got output as follows

> Map(Rate -> 6.2532, Ask -> 6.2531, id -> USDCNY, Bid -> 6.2533, Date
>   -> 4/28/2014, Time -> 6:15am)

From Here,

How can I  bind a Map to scala properties,

> class Currency(Rate:String, Ask:String, id:String, Bid:String,
>   Date:String, Time:String)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show more detail on what you are attempting and what you have already tried. What JSON library are you using (or are you just processing this data as a String)? What kind of Scala object are you trying to extract?

Comment: Hope now my question makes some sense...

Comment: @BalaB I've updated my answer based on the additional details you provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many different ways of doing this, here is a straightforward one using [Argonaut](http://argonaut.io/). For more ways of handling JSON in Scala, see [What JSON library to use in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054018/json-library-for-scala) and [How to parse JSON in Scala using standard Scala classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170949/how-to-parse-json-in-scala-using-standard-scala-classes)

```
import argonaut._, Argonaut._

case class Rate(id : String, rate : Double, date : java.util.Date, ask : Double, bid : Double)
object Rate {    
  val dateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy h:mma")

  implicit def RateDecodeJson : DecodeJson[Rate] =
    DecodeJson(cursor => {
      val c = cursor --\ "query" --\ "results" --\ "rate"
      for {
        /* you can also access other fields of the JSON here, e.g. 
         * lang <- (cursor --\ "query" --\ "lang").as[String].map(new java.util.Locale(_))
         */
        id <- (c --\ "id").as[String]
        rate <- (c --\ "Rate").as[String].map(_.toDouble)
        date <- (c --\ "Date").as[String]
        time <- (c --\ "Time").as[String]
        ask <- (c --\ "Ask").as[String].map(_.toDouble)
        bid <- (c --\ "Bid").as[String].map(_.toDouble)
      } yield Rate(id, rate, dateFormat.parse(date + " " + time), ask, bid)})
}

object ArgonautExample extends App{
  val json = """{
      "query":{
        "count":1,
        "created":"2014-04-28T07:33:09Z",
        "lang":"en-US",
        "results":{
          "rate":{
            "id":"USDCNY",
            "Rate":"6.2489",
            "Date":"4/28/2014",
            "Time":"3:30am",
            "Ask":"6.2494",
            "Bid":"6.2484"
          }
        }
      }
    }"""

  val rate = Parse.decodeOption[Rate](json).get
  println(rate)
}
```

Note: You probably want to handle date and time in a slightly more sophisticated manner, e.g., using locales, etc.

If you don't mind the fields of `Rate` being all of type `String` (which is what the JSON delivers them as), you can also use the simpler version

```
case class Rate(id : String, rate : String, date : String, time : String, ask : String, bid : String)
object Rate {
  implicit def RateCodecJson : CodecJson[Rate] =
    casecodec6(Rate.apply, Rate.unapply)("id", "Rate", "Date", "Time", "Ask", "Bid")
}
```

and then first parse the whole JSON

```
val parsedJson = Parse.parseOption(json).get
```

and access and decode the relevant part

```
val rateJson = (parsedJson -|| List("query", "results", "rate")).get
val rate = rateJson.as[Rate].value.get
```