# get Json Values in Scala scala.util.parsing.json.JSON

Tags: java, json, scala, loops, dictionary

I am new in **Scala** and I want to extract some values from **json**

I have a big json data as a string and I want to extract only `review_score` value, I am using `import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON`
 library.

`var values = JSON.parseFull(bigJson)`

My problem is, after parsing to json, How I get the `reviewDetails` Map?

[image: a screen shot of received values]

Comment: Personally I've only used the jackson library, where extracting from a case class would enable you to access reviewDetails by => values.reviewDetails - I'm assuming this isn't the case here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`parseFull` will return an `Option[Any]` which contains either a `List[Any]` if the JSON string specifies an array, or a `Map[String,Any]` if the JSON string specifies an object, as the documentation states.

In your case, the value you want to retrieve is a key-value pair in a map which is itself a key-value pair of the global map.

It is a bit ugly, but since you know the structure of your JSON, a combination of `get` with `asInstanceOf`, will permit you to get the typed value you want.

```
val jsonObject = JSON.parseFull("...")
val globalMap = x.get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
val reviewMap = globalMap.get("reviewDetails").get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
val reviewScore = reviewMap.get("review_score").get.asInstanceOf[Double]
```

Note that here I use `get` "safely" because the value is known to exist in your context, but you can also use `isEmpty` and `getOrElse`.

If you want a scalable code, you can effectively look at [How to parse JSON in Scala using standard Scala classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170949/how-to-parse-json-in-scala-using-standard-scala-classes)

Comment: Thanks, but I get `java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get` error at line 3 where `reviewMap`

Comment: @Alaeddine Sorry, it should have been `globalMap.get("reviewDetails")` instead of "review_details".

Comment: What is `x` (the invoking object to `get`)? Is it supposed to be `jsonObject`?