# Relevant Regular Expression in scala

Tags: regex, scala, replace

I want to keep only the last term of a string separated by dots

**Example:**

My string is:

> abc"val1.val2.val3.val4"zzz

Expected string after i use regex:

> abc"val4"zzz

Which means i want the content from left-hand side which was separated with dot (**.**)

The most relevant I tried was

```
val json="""abc"val1.val2.val3.val4"zzz"""
val sortie="""(([A-Za-z0-9]*)\.([A-Za-z0-9]*){2,10})\.([A-Za-z0-9]*)""".r.replaceAllIn(json, a=>  a.group(3))
```

the result was:

> abc".val4"zzz

Can you tell me if you have different solution for regex please?

Thanks

Comment: Are there always going to be 4 values?

Comment: Maybe `json.replaceAll("(\\w+\")[^\"]*\\.([^\"]*\")", "$1$2")`?

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
val s = """abc"val1.val2.val3.val4"zzz"""
val res = "(\\w+\")[^\"]*\\.([^\"]*\")".r replaceAllIn (s, "$1$2")
println(res)
// => abc"val4"zzz
```

See the [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/WaGlYV)

**Pattern details**:

- `(\\w+\")` - Group 1 capturing 1+ word chars and a `"`
- `[^\"]*` - 0+ chars other than `"`
- `\\.` - a dot
- `([^\"]*\")` - Group 2 capturing 0+ chars other than `"` and then a `"`.

The `$1` is the backreference to the first group and `$2` inserts the text inside Group 2.

Comment: Thanks for your help on that regex/eclipse question, too ;-)

Comment: Well,in real life, it's a big Json where some objects are prefixed with a domain name. For example: "bic3Reference":{"fr.laposte.colis.schema.pivot.common.parcel.ParcelReference":{"type":{"string":"c"},"ref":"b","key":{"string":"a"}}},"customerParcelReference":{"fr.laposte.colis.schema.pivot.common.parcel.CustomerParcelReference":{"ref":"CAB CY32"}}

Comment: Then use approapriate tools, see [How to parse JSON in Scala using standard Scala classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170949/how-to-parse-json-in-scala-using-standard-scala-classes)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe without Regex at all:

```
scala> json.split("\"").map(_.split("\\.").last).mkString("\"")
res4: String = abc"val4"zzz
```

This assumes you want each "token" (separated by `"`) to become the last dot-separated inner token.

Comment: Well,in real life, it's a big Json where some objects are prefixed with a domain name