# How to Parse Json on Scala

Tags: json, scala, parsing

Here, I attached my code (pure Scala)

```
    package stock

    import scala.io.Source._
    import java.util.Scanner
    import java.io.File
    import scala.util.parsing.json._

    object StockDetails {

    def main(args : Array[String]){

        val filePath = new java.io.File(".").getCanonicalPath
        val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile(filePath +"/stock/file.txt")
        // file.txt --> contains 
        // line 1 --> GOOG - 50, MS - 10
        // line 2 --> SGI - 100, GOOG - 50, MS - 10
        // line 3 --> GOOG - 100, AMZN - 90, MS - 80
     for(line <- source.getLines()) {

            val txt = line.split(",")
            val s1 = txt.map{ss => 
            val s2 = ss.split(" - ")(0).trim()
            val holder = fromURL("http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q="+s2).mkString
            println("holder===========",holder) 
            val s3 = holder.split("//")(1)
            println("s3================",s3) 
            val s4 = JSON.parseFull(s3).get
            println("s4==========================",s4)

            }
          }
        }
     }
```

O\P:

```
(holder==========================,
// [
{
"id": "660479"
,"t" : "MS"
,"e" : "NYSE"
,"l" : "43.06"
,"l_fix" : "43.06"
,"l_cur" : "43.06"
,"s": "0"
,"ltt":"4:02PM EST"
,"lt" : "Dec 23, 4:02PM EST"
,"lt_dts" : "2016-12-23T16:02:12Z"
,"c" : "+0.27"
,"c_fix" : "0.27"
,"cp" : "0.63"
,"cp_fix" : "0.63"
,"ccol" : "chg"
,"pcls_fix" : "42.79"
}
])

(s3================, 
[{
"id": "660479"
,"t" : "MS"
,"e" : "NYSE"
,"l" : "43.06"
,"l_fix" : "43.06"
,"l_cur" : "43.06"
,"s": "0"
,"ltt":"4:02PM EST"
,"lt" : "Dec 23, 4:02PM EST"
,"lt_dts" : "2016-12-23T16:02:12Z"
,"c" : "+0.27"
,"c_fix" : "0.27"
,"cp" : "0.63"
,"cp_fix" : "0.63"
,"ccol" : "chg"
,"pcls_fix" : "42.79"
}
])

    (s4==========================,
 List(Map(
    e -> NYSE, 
    s -> 0, 
    cp_fix -> 0.63, 
    l_cur -> 43.06, 
    ccol -> chg, 
    t -> MS, 
    pcls_fix -> 42.79, 
    id -> 660479, 
    l -> 43.06, 
    l_fix -> 43.06, 
    c_fix -> 0.27, 
    c -> +0.27, 
    cp -> 0.63, 
    lt -> Dec 23, 4:02PM EST, 
    lt_dts -> 2016-12-23T16:02:12Z, 
    ltt -> 4:02PM EST)))
```

Here, I want the " l " value but i can't able to get it, When I used map/ foreach it's returned as

```
$ scalac Stock.scala
Stock.scala:30: error: value map is not a member of Any
                val s5 = s4.map{ ex => ex }
                                            ^
one error found
```

And tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170949/how-to-parse-json-in-scala-using-standard-scala-classes) but i can't able to get it, Here what i do?

Comment: Package `scala.util.parsing.json` is deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... the thing is that you have S4 as `Any`.

```
// since we know that s4 is supposed to be a List
// we can type-cast it to List[Any]
val s4List = s4.asInstanceOf[List[Any]]

// now we also know that s4 was actually a list of Map's
// and those maps look to be String -> String
// so we can type-cast all the things inside list to Map[String, String]
val s4MapList = s4List.map(m => m.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]])

// and we also know that s4 is a List of Map's and has length 1
val map = s4MapList(0)

// lets say you wanted id
val idOption = map.get("id")

// but we know that map has a key "id"
// so we can just get that
val id = map("id")
```

Note :: This is not the recommended way of doing things in Scala, but can help you understand what are you supposed to do on a basic level. Keep learning... and you will come to understand better ways to deal with things.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing using `JSON.parseFull` returns option of any.

```
scala> JSON.parseFull("""{"key": "value"}""")
res2: Option[Any] = Some(Map(key -> value))
```

So, use pattern matching to extract the types you want.

or type cast (not recommended)