# how to iterate each element of json file using scala

Tags: json, scala

JSON FILE:
need to iterate each element using scala.read the JSON file in scala and iterate over the each element & and add it the particular list.

Input:

`{"details": [{"Level": "1", "member": "age", "claim": "age"}, {"Level": "2", "member": "dob", "claim": "dob"}, {"Level": "2", "member": "name", "claim": "name"}]}`

`output:`

`Memberlist=list(list(age),list(dob),list(name))`

`Claimlist=list(list(age),list(dob),list(name))`

Comment: question not clear. If you need any help, then provide clear question.

Comment: Provide proper `input` json and expected `output`.

Comment: i need to iterate each string of json file format.u just say how to iterate elements of json file..thats enough..thanks in advance.

Comment: Input and outpts are mentioned over there...

Comment: is `level : 2` in array of details for element-id 1 and 2 correct?

Comment: if level 2 means we need to add the elemnt to 2 nd list,likewise if level 1 means add the element to list 1.

Comment: what would be the output for this input `{"Level": "2", "member": "dob_1", "claim": "dob_1"}, {"Level": "2", "member": "name_2", "claim": "name_2"}`

Comment: member=list(list(dob_1),name_2))            
 claim=list(list(dob_1),name_2))                   2 lists ( member and claim.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple and recursive path to traverse JSON objects in Scala, assuming you're using the Play Framework

```
val jsonDetails:JsValue = Json.parse("""
{"details":
[{"Level": "1", "member":"age", "claim":"age"},
 {"Level": "2", "member": "dob", "claim": "dob2"},
 {"Level": "2", "member":"name1", "claim":"name"}
]}
""")
var pathToFirstLevel = (jsonDetails\"details"\0\"Level")
var allIstancesOfMember = (jsonDetails\\"member")
```

Will return

```
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsLookupResult = JsDefined("1")
res2: Seq[play.api.libs.json.JsValue] = List("age", "dob", "name1")
```

You can grab the data you're looking for and populate your lists, but you'll need to convert the JsValues to values Scala can work with (use .as[T] not asInstanceOf[T])

You can also use map

```
var allIstancesOfMember =(jsonDetails\\"member").map(_.as[String])
```

There's loads of information on traversing JSON elements in Scala using the Play Framework at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson

does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this solution can fit for your requirement.

Some concrete classes used for extraction

```
class CC[T] { def unapply(a:Any):Option[T] = Some(a.asInstanceOf[T]) }

object M extends CC[Map[String, Any]]
object L extends CC[List[Any]]
object S extends CC[String]
```

`ListBuffer` for output.

```
val memberList = ListBuffer.empty[Any]
val claimList = ListBuffer.empty[Any]
```

`for` comprehension to iterate over list of details and extract each detail.

```
for {
     Some(M(map)) <- List(JSON.parseFull(s))
     L(details) = map("details")
     M(language) <- details
     //S(level) = language("Level") //Not so sure how to use this variable
     S(member) = language("member")
     S(claim) = language("claim")
     } yield {
         memberList += List(member) //List is used to match your output.
         claimList += List(claim)  //List is used to match your output.
     }
```

Output

```
println(memberList) 
//ListBuffer(List(m_age), List(m_dob), List(m_name))
println(claimList)
//ListBuffer(List(c_age), List(c_dob), List(c_name))
```

Credits to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170949/how-to-parse-json-in-scala-using-standard-scala-classes?answertab=votes#tab-top)