# Parsing simple json string using scala built in functions

Tags: scala

I am trying to parse a simple json by using scala built in functions. But till now no positive result.Could you please provide any sample code or ideas to implement the below logic.

For example, I have a json input like this

```
val input_json = {"name" : "john", "id" : 101}
```

now my requirement is to parse the above json and store name and id values into two variables namely v1 & v2 by using scala built in functions.

Please provide sample code for parsing above json.

Comment: Please share what you have tried already.

Comment: Well, ideally you should try something like: https://github.com/json4s/json4s

Comment: Please have a look at the following post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170949/how-to-parse-json-in-scala-using-standard-scala-classes

Comment: Just I am trying to use scala.util.parsing.json.JSON package. But didn't get clarity how to use it. In pl/sql(Oracle,Postgres) it is pretty easy to handle JSON by using simple methods. Do we have any such kind of methods in scala

Answer (score 0):

you can use `scala.util.parsing.json.JSON` `parseFull` as below

```
val input_json = """{"name":"john","id":101}"""

import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON
val (v1, v2) = JSON.parseFull(input_json).collect{case map: Map[String, Any] => (map("name"), map("id"))}.get

//v1: Any = john
//v2: Any = 101.0
```

You can *cast* them later on

Comment: You have to add the JSON as a dependency to your project. It does not come built in anymore. It is deprecated.

Comment: well, I am using Scala 2.11.8 and its not deprecated in that. @ChaitanyaWaikar

Comment: I am sorry if I committed any mistake. I will take down my answer. I am trying to help others.

Comment: This is deprecated as of scala 2.11
https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators