# How to filter nested Lists and Maps in scala

Tags: json, scala, dictionary, filter

I am trying to read a json file in order to calculate some metrics in scala. I managed to read the file and to conduct some outer filters but I have troubles understanding how to filter nested lists and maps.

Here is an example code (the real json is longer):

```
  val rawData = """[
  {
    "technology": "C",
    "users": [
    {
      "rating": 5,
      "completed": false,
      "user": {
        "id": 11111,
        "paid": true
      }
    },
    {
      "rating": 4,
      "completed": false,
      "user": {
        "id": 22222,
        "paid": false
      }
    }
    ],
    "title": "CS50"
  },
  {
    "technology": "C++",
    "users": [
    {
      "rating": 3,
      "completed": true,
      "user": {
        "id": 33333,
        "paid": false
      }
    },
    {
      "rating": 5,
      "completed": true,
      "user": {
        "id": 44444,
        "paid": false
      }
    }
    ],
    "title": "Introduction to C++"
  },
  {
    "technology": "Haskell",
    "users": [
    {
      "rating": 5,
      "completed": false,
      "user": {
        "id": 55555,
        "paid": false
      }
    },
    {
      "rating": null,
      "completed": true,
      "user": {
        "id": 66666,
        "paid": false
      }
    }
    ],
    "title": "Course on Haskell"
  }
  ]"""

  val data = rawData.toString.split("\n").toSeq.map(_.trim).filter(_ != "").mkString("")
```

I managed to get a list containing the 3 titles:

```
import scala.util.parsing.json._
val parsedData = JSON.parseFull(data)
val listTitles = parsedData.get.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, Any]]].map( { case e: Map[String, Any] => e("title").toString }  )
```

Here are my 3 questions:

1. Is that a good approach to obtain the list of the 3 titles?
2. How to obtain a List containing the number of paid users for each of
   the latter 3 titles?
3. How to obtain a List containing the number of users who have
   completed the course for each of the latter 3 titles?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: You should no longer use the json parser from Scala. There are better altnatives, e.g. https://circe.github.io/circe/. If you still want to go the stony path, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4186090/4432837

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer suggested, you should use the play-json library. It's really powerful and has tons of features including object mapping and parsing and error handling.

```
  import play.api.libs.json._
  import play.api.data.validation.ValidationError

  case class User(id: String, paid: Boolean)
  object User {
    implicit val format: OFormat[User] = Json.format[User]
  }

  case class UserCourseStat(rating: Int, completed: Boolean, user: User)
  object UserCourseStat {
    implicit val format: OFormat[UserCourseStat] = Json.format[UserCourseStat]
  }

  case class Data(technology: String, title: String, users: List[UserCourseStat])
  object Data {
    implicit val format: OFormat[Data] = Json.format[Data]
  }

  val jsString = """[{"technology":"C","users":[{"rating":5,"completed":false,"user":{"id":11111,"paid":true}},{"rating":4,"completed":false,"user":{"id":22222,"paid":false}}],"title":"CS50"},{"technology":"C++","users":[{"rating":3,"completed":true,"user":{"id":33333,"paid":false}},{"rating":5,"completed":true,"user":{"id":44444,"paid":false}}],"title":"Introduction to C++"},{"technology":"Haskell","users":[{"rating":5,"completed":false,"user":{"id":55555,"paid":false}},{"rating":null,"completed":true,"user":{"id":66666,"paid":false}}],"title":"Course on Haskell"}]"""

  val rowData: JsValue = Json.parse(jsString)

  rowData.validate[List[Data]] match {
    case JsSuccess(dataList: List[Data], _) =>
      val chosenTitles = List("Course on Haskell", "Introduction to C++", "CS50")

      //map of each chosen title to sequence of it's users
      val chosenTitleToUsersMap = chosenTitles.map { title =>
        title -> dataList.filter(_.title == title)
          .flatMap(_.users.map(_.user))
          .toSet
      }.toMap
      //map of each chosen title to sequence of it's paid users
      val chosenTitleToPaidUsersMap = chosenTitleToUsersMap.map { case (title, users) =>
        title -> users.filter(_.paid)
      }

      //Calculate users who have completed each of the chosen title
      val allUsers = dataList.flatMap(_.users.map(_.user)).toSet

      val usersWhoCompletedAllChosenTitles = allUsers.filter{ user =>
        chosenTitles.forall { title =>
          chosenTitleToUsersMap.get(title).flatten.contains(user)
        }
      }

    case JsError(errors: Seq[(JsPath, Seq[ValidationError])]) =>
      //handle the error case
      ???
  }
```

Regarding the 3 questions you had:

> 1. Is that a good approach to obtain the list of the 3 titles?

I can see 2 unsafe operations there, asInstanceOf and e("title"), latter one is because of not using the .get(key) method of the Map, it will throw and exception if key not found.

> 2. How to obtain a List containing the number of paid users for each of the latter 3 titles?

Evaluated above in val named "chosenTitleToPaidUsersMap"

> 3. How to obtain a List containing the number of users who have completed the course for each of the latter 3 titles?

Evaluated above in val named "usersWhoCompletedAllChosenTitles"

Answer (score 0):

You can use play-json library to parse and retrieve the field you want. For example:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

val rawData1 = Json.parse("""[{"technology":"C","users":[{"rating":5,"completed":false,"user":{"id":11111,"paid":true}},{"rating":4,"completed":false,"user":{"id":22222,"paid":false}}],"title":"CS50"},{"technology":"C++","users":[{"rating":3,"completed":true,"user":{"id":33333,"paid":false}},{"rating":5,"completed":true,"user":{"id":44444,"paid":false}}],"title":"Introduction to C++"},{"technology":"Haskell","users":[{"rating":5,"completed":false,"user":{"id":55555,"paid":false}},{"rating":null,"completed":true,"user":{"id":66666,"paid":false}}],"title":"Course on Haskell"}]""")

val resultedList = (rawData1 \\ "title").toList.map(_.as[String])
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the [json4s](http://json4s.org/) library. It allows you to extract your data into case classes:

```
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parseOpt
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

case class Tech(technology: String, users: Seq[TechUser], title: String)
case class TechUser(rating: Option[Int], completed: Boolean, user: UserInfo)
case class UserInfo(id: Int, paid: Boolean)

val rawData = """..."""
val Some(json) = parseOpt(rawData)
val Some(data) = json.extractOpt[List[Tech]]
```

After doing this, `data` is a regular Scala data structure that you can manipulate as you wish. For example, if you want to find for which title there is a user whose id is divisible by 5, it's done like this:

```
data.find(_.users.exists(_.user.id % 5 == 0)).map(_.title)
// Result: Some("Course on Haskell")
```

The answers to your three questions are one-liners just like this one, but I leave them to you as an exercise.