# Parsing JSON based off of schema with recursive fields in Scala

Tags: json, scala, intellij-idea, jsonschema, scala-macros

I have a json-schema (https://json-schema.org) with recursive fields, and I would like to programmatically parse json that adheres to the schema in Scala.

One option is to use Argus (https://github.com/aishfenton/Argus), but the only issue is that it uses Scala macros, so a solution that uses this library isn't supported by IntelliJ.

What's the recommended way to perform a task like this in Scala, preferably something that plays well with IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/) is a great library for working with JSON. The following example uses [semi automatic decoding](https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/semiauto-derivation.html). Circe also has guides for [automatic decoding](https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/auto-derivation.html) and for using [custom codecs](https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/custom-codecs.html).

```
import io.circe.Decoder
import io.circe.parser.decode
import io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveDecoder

object Example {

  case class MyClass(name: String, code: Int, sub: MySubClass)
  case class MySubClass(value: Int)
  implicit val myClassDecoder:    Decoder[MyClass]    = deriveDecoder
  implicit val mySubClassDecoder: Decoder[MySubClass] = deriveDecoder

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val input = """{"name": "Bob", "code": 200, "sub": {"value": 42}}"""
    println(decode[MyClass](input).fold(_ => "parse failed", _.toString))
  }

}
```

Comment: Circe does support recursive fields, it solved our problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you look at https://github.com/circe/circe , it is pretty good to parse Json with typed format.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean with recursive fields.   But there's lots of different libraries for parsing json. You could use lift-json
 https://github.com/lift/framework/tree/master/core/json

Which seems popular, at least from what I've seen here on Stackoverflow. But I personally am very comfortable with and prefer play.json
 https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson#Json
(Also, I use IntelliJ and work in the Play-framework)

If you really don't want to use any special libraries, someone tried to do that here
[How to parse JSON in Scala using standard Scala classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170949/how-to-parse-json-in-scala-using-standard-scala-classes)